# Redirect URL when there are trailing slashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an app which is build using NextJS. When it's in production, it allows trailing slashes but breaking a bunch of other stuff. It gives me the following error:

> Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https:' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://myapp.com' and URL 'https://myapp.com///'.
>   Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https:' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://myapp.com' and URL 'https://myapp.com///'.

I would like to simply redirect to the correct address whenever there are trailing slashes.

So for example, user types: `myapp.com///`, I would like to redirect them to `myapp.com`, using NextJS routing. Is this possible? How do I do this?

Comment: just throwing darts at it...can you just use regex or .length to see if there is anything else added to end then reroute it if that's the case?

Comment: What version of Next.js are you using? Trailing slashes were broken on 5.0, but should work on `next@canary`.

Answer (score 0):

Your app shouldn't support this kind of trailing slashes in the first place. myapp.com/ is one thing, myapp.com/// is another thing.

AFAIK, Google also sees it that way, so if you allow multiple trailing slashes in your url Google will end up showing you a bunch of duplicates (as each url with an extra / delivers the same content as without it). If you're using NextJs, you care about SEO, most likely.

The correct solution is to always force a trailing slash on your urls. If you're running `express` you can use [connect-slashes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-slashes) on production to always force the trailing slash.

Beware, as this will break your /static/ folder. You can fix this with the express static middleware: `server.use(express.static('static'));`.

If, however, you're insistent on allowing multiple slashes, I'd strongly recommend clearing them server-side and showing a single `/`. So `myapp.com////` becomes `myapp.com/` after going through your middleware.

I'd modify the `connect-slashes` repo mentioned before or create my own. A simple regex to catch repetitive `/` at the end of your url should do the trick. replace it with just one and you're good to go.